# Setting compose key in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, compose-key

I just decided to give a try to Ubuntu 17.10, but as soon as I tried to set my compose Key, I can't find the place to do it.

Usually it was in Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Typing, but in this section I only find two options:

```
Switch to next input source
Switch to previous input source
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This options are available in GNOME Tweaks (`gnome-tweak-tool` package).

You can use search in GNOME Tweaks, or navigate to *Keyboard & Mouse* and set *Compose Key* here.

Comment: I installed `gnome-tweak-tool`, went to *Keyboard & Mouse*, but saw the compose key was disabled. I didn't find how to enable it.

Comment: OK, I got it: you have to click on the word "disabled" and a button appears. Not very user friendly.